# Regex to group attributes irrespective of sequence

Tags: c#, regex

I have to group the following string into groups irrespective of sequence.

```
<div>data-textBoxColor="#111" data-font=""Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif" data-titleColor="#fff"<div>
```

the output should be :

data-textBoxColor, #111
data-font, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif
data-titleColor, "#fff

I tried the following regex, but it did not pick the data-font as it as a nested quote.

```
(data-[a-z][^=]*)=("[a-z0-9-#][^"]*")
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You should consider using HTMLAgilityPack for this. Html is not a regular language, therefore regular expressions are not as effective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
(data-[a-z][^=]*)=("[a-z0-9"#][^=]*")
```

## [REGEX DEMO](http://rubular.com/r/8lToMY86ZU)

O/P:

[image]

Comment: Can you please post the link of the site where you took the screenshot, that would be very helpful.

Comment: This one also matches quotes at the begin and at the end. You need to strip them out with a substring.

Answer (score 0):

Cause that nested quote is a non-regular syntax.

You can only rely on the fact that the closing quote is followed by `data` or `<div>`:

Use this one:

`(data-[a-z][^=]*)="([a-z0-9#\-," ]*(?=" data|"<div>))"`

[Demo on RegEx101](http://regex101.com/r/aH8wC1)

Comment: It is matching last character additionally like this `f`,`1`,`f`

Comment: Simply don't look at group 3, you are interested in groups 1, 2

Comment: I've removed parenthesis so you only get groups 1,2